# Selenium - Iterating Through Drop Down Menu - Let Page Load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate through player seasons on NBA.com and pull shooting statistics after each click of the season dropdown menu. After each click, I get the error message "list index out of range" for:

`headers = table[1].findAll('th')`

It seems to me that the page doesn't load all the way before the source data is saved.

Looking at other similar questions, I have tried using an `browser.implicitly_wait()` for each loop, but I am still getting the same error. It also doesn't seem that the browser waits after more than the first iteration of the loop.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

player_id = str(1629216)
    
url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/player/' + player_id + "/shooting/"
browser = Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label/select'))
options = select.options

for index in range(0, len(options)):
    select.select_by_index(index)

    browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    src = browser.page_source
    parser = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml") 
    table = parser.findAll("div", attrs = {"class":"nba-stat-table__overflow"})

    headers = table[1].findAll('th')
    headerlist = [h.text.strip() for h in headers[1:]]
    headerlist = [a for a in headerlist if not '\n' in a]
    headerlist.append('AST%')
    headerlist.append('UAST%')

    row_labels = table[1].findAll("td", {"class": "first"})
    row_labels_list = [r.text.strip() for r in row_labels[0:]]

    rows = table[1].findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText().strip() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')[1:]] for i in range(len(rows))]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=player_stats, columns=headerlist, index = row_labels_list)

    print(df)
```

Comment: you'll only need to set implicit wait once.  (it's global)  But it doesn't seem like you're using webdriver calls anyway... it's all using page source (which might not be good depending on how the site works...)  If the site uses javascript to populate the DOM, you'll want to use the webdriver to get your values.  Your loop goes from 0 to length... you may want 0 to length-1 there.... and for table[1] you may need table[0].  Check the value of your table array.

Comment: Do you really need selenium for this? The data might be available through the [api](https://pypi.org/project/nba-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. I used `time.sleep(1)` at the top of the loop to give the browser a second to load all the way. Without this delay, the pages source code did not have the appropriate table that I am scraping.

Responding to those who answered - I did not want to go the api route, but I have seen people scrape nba.com using that method. Table[1] is the correct table; just needed the source code a chance to load after the I loop through the season dropdown.

```
    select.select_by_index(index)
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    src = browser.page_source
    parser = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml") 
    table = parser.findAll("div", attrs = {"class":"nba-stat-table__overflow"})

    headers = table[1].findAll('th')
    headerlist = [h.text.strip() for h in headers[1:]]
    headerlist = [a for a in headerlist if not '\n' in a]
    headerlist.append('AST%')
    headerlist.append('UAST%')

    row_labels = table[1].findAll("td", {"class": "first"})
    row_labels_list = [r.text.strip() for r in row_labels[0:]]

    rows = table[1].findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText().strip() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')[1:]] for i in range(len(rows))]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=player_stats, columns=headerlist, index = row_labels_list)
    
    

    print(df)
```